# TSLint - Promises must be handled appropriately with `finally`

Tags: typescript, q, tslint

I'm getting this error from TSLint and I'm trying to understand why it is complaining about.

I have a function which invokes another method which returns a promise but the first function does not return the promise because it just waits for it to finish and update an internal state.

I've simplified it to this function and just use `Q()` to simulate an invocation that returns a promise.

```
export function DoSomethingAsync(): void {
    Q().then(r => {
        console.log('test');
    }).catch(err => {
        log.error("wow");
    }).finally(() => {
        log.info("at finally")
    });
}
```

When I run `tslint` on my project now I'm getting the following error:

ERROR: C:/dev/local_cache_service.ts[31, 5]: Promises must be handled appropriately

If I remove the `finally` call tslint passes without errors.

```
export function DoSomethingAsync(): void {
    Q().then(r => {
        console.log('test');
    }).catch(err => {
        log.error("wow");
    });
}
```

When I create the same function on a seed typescript project this behavior does not reproduce...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a complaint from the [no-floating-promises](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises) rule. As per its description:

> Creating a Promise and not storing or returning it may let other code run independently of its result. This can cause unexpected and/or non-deterministic behavior depending on external timing factors.
>
> It’s typically better to return Promises from functions that start them, then handle them in calling code.
>
> Use `no-unused-expression` in addition to this rule to reveal even more floating promises.

Specifically in your case, it's because you're running code in a `.finally` block *after* the `.catch` block. That's considered dangerous by the rule because if the code within the `.finally` throws an error, it'll be unhandled by the calling code.

The best thing for you to do would be to `return` the promise, so the function's return type is a Promise/Q instead of `void`.

Tip: you can run `tslint -t stylish` or `tslint -t verbose` to see rule names along with their complaints!

Comment: Thank you. Return the promise will not solve the problem, it will just move it to the called of this function, which in this case is a private function and by design I don't want to return this promise as it's an internal operation that the caller should not wait on.

Comment: In that case, two quick options:

* Put a `// tslint:disable-next-line:no-floating-promises` above the line being complained about
* Put a `.catch` after the `.finally`, which will handle the case of the `.finally` code throwing an error

You could also consider having something that receives these floating promises and `.catch`es them. `safePromiseCatcher(Q().then(...));`.

Answer (score -2):

The solution was to add a call to `.done()` at the end of the promise call chain.

From what I understood `done` converts any unhandled exceptions to a regular unhandled exception.

Comment: Property 'done' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'